# Printing content in Listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to print the content in my listbox after the program is run (The courses that are typed in, Total hours, Quantity Points, Total GPA).  It is opening up my printer options but printing a blank page every time...

```
Public Class Form1

Dim QualityPoints As Double
Dim CourseName, hours As String

Private Sub btnTotalHours_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTotalHours.Click

    txtBoxTotalHours.Text = NumericUpDown1.Value + NumericUpDown2.Value + NumericUpDown3.Value + NumericUpDown4.Value + NumericUpDown5.Value + NumericUpDown6.Value + NumericUpDown7.Value + NumericUpDown8.Value

End Sub

Private Sub btnTotalQualityPoints_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTotalQualityPoints.Click

    Select Case txtBoxGrade1.Text
        Case "A"
            QualityPoints += (4 * NumericUpDown1.Value)
        Case "B"
            QualityPoints += (3 * NumericUpDown1.Value)
        Case "C"
            QualityPoints += (2 * NumericUpDown1.Value)
        Case "D"
            QualityPoints += (1 * NumericUpDown1.Value)
        Case "F"
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown1.Value)
        Case " "
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown1.Value)

    End Select

    Select Case txtBoxGrade2.Text
        Case "A"
            QualityPoints += (4 * NumericUpDown2.Value)
        Case "B"
            QualityPoints += (3 * NumericUpDown2.Value)
        Case "C"
            QualityPoints += (2 * NumericUpDown2.Value)
        Case "D"
            QualityPoints += (1 * NumericUpDown2.Value)
        Case "F"
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown2.Value)
        Case " "
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown2.Value)

    End Select

    Select Case txtBoxGrade3.Text
        Case "A"
            QualityPoints += (4 * NumericUpDown3.Value)
        Case "B"
            QualityPoints += (3 * NumericUpDown3.Value)
        Case "C"
            QualityPoints += (2 * NumericUpDown3.Value)
        Case "D"
            QualityPoints += (1 * NumericUpDown3.Value)
        Case "F"
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown3.Value)
        Case " "
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown3.Value)

    End Select

    Select Case txtBoxGrade4.Text
        Case "A"
            QualityPoints += (4 * NumericUpDown4.Value)
        Case "B"
            QualityPoints += (3 * NumericUpDown4.Value)
        Case "C"
            QualityPoints += (2 * NumericUpDown4.Value)
        Case "D"
            QualityPoints += (1 * NumericUpDown4.Value)
        Case "F"
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown4.Value)
        Case " "
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown4.Value)

    End Select

    Select Case txtBoxGrade5.Text
        Case "A"
            QualityPoints += (4 * NumericUpDown5.Value)
        Case "B"
            QualityPoints += (3 * NumericUpDown5.Value)
        Case "C"
            QualityPoints += (2 * NumericUpDown5.Value)
        Case "D"
            QualityPoints += (1 * NumericUpDown5.Value)
        Case "F"
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown5.Value)
        Case " "
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown5.Value)

    End Select

    Select Case txtBoxGrade6.Text
        Case "A"
            QualityPoints += (4 * NumericUpDown6.Value)
        Case "B"
            QualityPoints += (3 * NumericUpDown6.Value)
        Case "C"
            QualityPoints += (2 * NumericUpDown6.Value)
        Case "D"
            QualityPoints += (1 * NumericUpDown6.Value)
        Case "F"
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown6.Value)
        Case " "
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown6.Value)

    End Select

    Select Case txtBoxGrade7.Text
        Case "A"
            QualityPoints += (4 * NumericUpDown7.Value)
        Case "B"
            QualityPoints += (3 * NumericUpDown7.Value)
        Case "C"
            QualityPoints += (2 * NumericUpDown7.Value)
        Case "D"
            QualityPoints += (1 * NumericUpDown7.Value)
        Case "F"
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown7.Value)
        Case " "
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown7.Value)

    End Select

    Select Case txtBoxGrade8.Text
        Case "A"
            QualityPoints += (4 * NumericUpDown8.Value)
        Case "B"
            QualityPoints += (3 * NumericUpDown8.Value)
        Case "C"
            QualityPoints += (2 * NumericUpDown8.Value)
        Case "D"
            QualityPoints += (1 * NumericUpDown8.Value)
        Case "F"
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown8.Value)
        Case " "
            QualityPoints += (0 * NumericUpDown8.Value)

    End Select

    txtBoxTotalQualityPoints.Text = QualityPoints

End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

    txtBoxCourse1.Clear()
    txtBoxCourse2.Clear()
    txtBoxCourse3.Clear()
    txtBoxCourse4.Clear()
    txtBoxCourse5.Clear()
    txtBoxCourse6.Clear()
    txtBoxCourse7.Clear()
    txtBoxCourse8.Clear()

    txtBoxGrade1.Clear()
    txtBoxGrade2.Clear()
    txtBoxGrade3.Clear()
    txtBoxGrade4.Clear()
    txtBoxGrade5.Clear()
    txtBoxGrade6.Clear()
    txtBoxGrade7.Clear()
    txtBoxGrade8.Clear()

    txtBoxTotalGPA.Clear()
    txtBoxTotalHours.Clear()
    txtBoxTotalQualityPoints.Clear()

    NumericUpDown1.Value = 0
    NumericUpDown2.Value = 0
    NumericUpDown3.Value = 0
    NumericUpDown4.Value = 0
    NumericUpDown5.Value = 0
    NumericUpDown6.Value = 0
    NumericUpDown7.Value = 0
    NumericUpDown8.Value = 0


    lstBoxResults.Items.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    Dim semester As String
    Dim totalGPA As Double = QualityPoints / txtBoxTotalHours.Text

    semester = CStr(lstBoxResults.Text)
    txtBoxTotalGPA.Text = CStr(totalGPA)
    txtBoxTotalGPA.Text = Math.Round(totalGPA, 3)

    If radButtonFall.Checked Then

        semester = "Fall"

    ElseIf radButtonSpring.Checked Then

        semester = "Spring"

    ElseIf radButtonSummer.Checked Then

        semester = "Summer"

    End If


    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(semester & " " & "Semester : ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Total Hours : " & txtBoxTotalHours.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Total Qualit Points : " & txtBoxTotalQualityPoints.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Total " & semester & " " & "GPA : " & txtBoxTotalGPA.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Enrolled Courses : ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(txtBoxCourse1.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(txtBoxCourse2.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(txtBoxCourse3.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(txtBoxCourse4.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(txtBoxCourse5.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(txtBoxCourse6.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(txtBoxCourse7.Text)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(txtBoxCourse8.Text)

End Sub

Private Sub btnQuit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click

    End

End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Dim font1 As New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lstBoxResults.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 100, 100)

End Sub

Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

    PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()
    PrintDocument1.Print()

End Sub
```

End Class

Any Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this doesn't help you print, you should replace your `Select Case`s with something along these lines

At class level:

```
Private GradeToValue As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) _
    From {{"A", 4}, {"B", 3}, {"C", 2}, {"D", 1}, {"F", 0}, {" ", 0}}
```

In your button handler:

```
QualityPoints += (GradeToValue(txBoxGrade1.Text) * NumericUpDown1.Value)
QualityPoints += (GradeToValue(txBoxGrade2.Text) * NumericUpDown2.Value)
' etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/printform.html
It was all about print. Your problem only print blank cause your print_Page still not getting any object in there